# Solr datatype for interval provided by postgresql

Tags: postgresql, solr, sqldatatypes

I have Apache solr 7.4.0 which is connected to a postgresql datasource to pull data and indexing it.

Now in SQL query we have date difference which is coming as "interval".

Now I have tried using "string" as well as "date" data type which is giving below error

"error creating documents" ....

here are my sql

```
select 
 a.opn_dt AS openDate,
 a.clos_dt AS closeDate,
a.clos_dt - a.opn_dt AS Span from a;
```

and managed-schema where I have tried using data also

```
<field name="Span" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" default="" />
```

Please help how can I handle this "interval" value in managed-schema?

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like its not a issue at the solr end, but the query needs to be corrected by using the postgresql functions...I would suggest to build the correct query by using functions from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: the query in mysql is something like below select date_sub(now(), interval -3 hour) as past, now() as current, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,now(),date_sub(now(), interval -3 hour)) from dual; OR select date_sub(now(), interval -3 hour) as past, now() as current, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,now(),date_sub(now(), interval -3 hour)) from dual;